# Trigger copy event in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to trigger copy event from JavaScript/jQuery?
I want to simulate copy event by clicking on the button and can't find the way to do that.
I don't want to use ZeroClipboard and any other Flash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not possible without Flash or silverlight like plugins.